# Align element to parent of parent in one axis?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of tabs defined in (fairly) semantic HTML:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li class='tab'>
    <input type='radio' checked='checked' id='apples' name='fruit' />
    <label for='apples'>
      Apples
    </label>
    <div class='panel apples'>
      <p>Apples are red. </p> 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class='tab'>
    <input type='radio' id='bananas' name='fruit' />
    <label for='bananas'>
      Bananas
    </label>
    <div class='panel bananas'>
      <p>Bananas are yellow. </p> 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class='tab'>
    <input type='radio' id='cherries' name='fruit' />
    <label for='cherries'>
      Cherries
    </label>
    <div class='panel cherries'>
      <p>Cherries are... cherry. </p> 
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>
  This should always be below the tabs! 
</p>
```

I would like to use pure CSS to render the elements as tabs. The tabs should be buttons in a row. The selected panel should be displayed below the buttons and aligned to the left-most button. I have other elements that should be below the tab-panel. I do not want to use pixel-positioning so that the page resizes easily.

Here is the CSS I have tried so far:

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.tabs input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs .tab label {
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: #ff0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .panel {
  display: flex;
  background: #0ff;
}
```

This is almost there, but the selected panel is displayed below its button, rather than the left-most button.

I would like to do something like `position-x: absolute`, but I do not know if this is possible.

How can I align the selected panel with its parent's parent?

---

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkf7b8cy/

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve that with current markup structure using CSS alone, a script will be needed.

Your suggestion, to use `position: absolute` (there is no `position-x` by the way) will make the following elements, in this case the `p`, to jump up beneath/hide behind the `panel`'s , since their parent will collapse its height to 0, caused by absolute positioned `panel`'s.

With a markup change as follows it is possible though, where you put the `input` before the `ul`, and the `panel` after.

Also the `:checked` CSS rules needed an update.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkf7b8cy/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs .tab:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabs .tab label {
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio][id=apples]:checked ~ ul label[for=apples],
input[type=radio][id=bananas]:checked ~ ul label[for=bananas],
input[type=radio][id=cherries]:checked ~ ul label[for=cherries] {
  background: #ff0;
}

input[id=apples]:checked ~ .panel.apples,
input[id=bananas]:checked ~ .panel.bananas,
input[id=cherries]:checked ~ .panel.cherries {
  display: flex;
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' checked='checked' id='apples' name='fruit' />
<input type='radio' id='bananas' name='fruit' />
<input type='radio' id='cherries' name='fruit' />
<ul class='tabs'>
  <li class='tab'>
    <label for='apples'>
      Apples
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tab'>
    <label for='bananas'>
      Bananas
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tab'>
    <label for='cherries'>
      Cherries
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class='panel apples'>
  <p>Apples are red. </p>
</div>
<div class='panel bananas'>
  <p>Bananas are yellow. </p>
</div>
<div class='panel cherries'>
  <p>Cherries are... cherry. </p>
</div>


<p>
  This should always be below the tabs!
</p>
```

Comment: This is a reasonable solution but it has two (unavoidable?) downsides: 1) mark-up is not as clean since tabs and panels are split (imagine if there is no CSS); 2) A CSS rule is required for every tab. I will leave this unmarked for now, but have an upvote.

Comment: @sdgfsdh With the given requirements it needs to be like this. ...If to keep existing markup, you either need a script, or use position absolute, which will need a fixed top margin on your `p`. ...When you say _imagine if there is no CSS_, can you explain what you mean? Do you target device that don't understand CSS or is it simply if it doesn't load properly?